# Fitting 3 different slopes to data subgroups or fitting a single mixed-effects model, and which values to report

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm new to the world of mixed-effects models and trying to understand what method/results to report for my given data/question. I am trying to determine the coefficients of a regression model but have three sub-populations within the data. My question is 1) whether y is predicted from x at a likelihood much greater than chance and 2) whether the slope is essentially the same for each sub-population. I've simulated some data that shows this:

```r
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(grp=gl(3, 10, labels = LETTERS[1:3]))
dat$y <- 1:10+as.numeric(dat$grp)*3
dat$x <- 1:10+as.numeric(dat$grp)[rep(c(1,3,2), each=10)]
dat$x <- ifelse(dat$grp=="A", dat$x+10, dat$x)
dat$x <- ifelse(dat$grp=="C", dat$x+6, dat$x)
dat$y <- ifelse(dat$grp=="A", dat$y*0.5, dat$y)
dat$y <- dat$y+rnorm(30, sd = 0.5)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_smooth(color="black", method="lm") +
  geom_smooth(aes(color=grp), method="lm") +
  geom_point(aes(fill=grp), pch=21)
```

[image: scatterplot of the above data with ggplot lines of best fit]

Visually (and correctly, given that this data is simulated) the answers to my questions are relatively simple: yes, y is predicted from x, and kinda, with B ~ C > A. The question is how I should best show this statistically and what I should report for my actual data.

Obviously the overall (black) trend is incorrect and is an illustration of Simpson's paradox, so I'll ignore it entirely. The `ggplot` lines are fit independently to each sub-population with a basic call to `lm` that I can reproduce with a simple loop. These values then need to be corrected for multiple comparisons and I do so separately for the slopes and intercepts since I want to keep the FWER distinct for each.

```r
loop_vals <- do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(dat$grp), function(grp_i){
  broom::tidy(lm(y~x, data=dat[dat$grp==grp_i,]))
}))
p.adj <- c(p.adjust(loop_vals$p.value[c(1,3,5)]), p.adjust(loop_vals$p.value[c(2,4,6)]))
loop_vals$p.adj <- p.adj[c(1,4,2,5,3,6)]
```

```
  term        estimate std.error statistic      p.value        p.adj
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 (Intercept)   -3.29     0.901      -3.65 0.00650      0.0130      
2 x              0.459    0.0538      8.54 0.0000273    0.0000273   
3 (Intercept)    5.52     0.399      13.8  0.000000722  0.00000217  
4 x              0.936    0.0562     16.7  0.000000171  0.000000342 
5 (Intercept)    0.879    0.614       1.43 0.190        0.190       
6 x              1.07     0.0479     22.4  0.0000000167 0.0000000501
```

I can obtain these same values with an interaction-based model in a single call to `lm()`, but the significance values are wildly different (or I don't understand how the error propagates differently here). This likely just has to do with multiple comparisons?

```
broom::tidy(lm(y~x*grp, data=dat))
```

```
  term        estimate std.error statistic       p.value
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>
1 (Intercept)   -3.29     0.883      -3.72 0.00106      
2 x              0.459    0.0527      8.70 0.00000000686
3 grpB           8.81     0.959       9.18 0.00000000253
4 grpC           4.17     1.11        3.74 0.00100      
5 x:grpB         0.477    0.0746      6.39 0.00000131   
6 x:grpC         0.614    0.0746      8.23 0.0000000191
```

Alternatively, I can fit the data using a mixed effects model. Fitting this with random intercepts and fixed slopes gives reasonable results and an easily interpretable output, but I've heard mixed advice on trying to model a random effect with so few groups (less than 5):

```r
lme_fixed_slope_mod <- lme4::lmer(y~x+(1|grp), data=dat, REML = FALSE)
```

```
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 grp      (Intercept) 6.8323  
 Residual             0.9156  
Number of obs: 30, groups:  grp, 3
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)            x  
     0.3904       0.8171
```

Finally, I can fit the data with random slopes *and* random intercepts. I've been told this is generally a good idea but worry that it won't answer my overall question about the slope estimate as clearly. Doing this returns predictions that are very similar to (but distinct from!) the values obtained from the `lm` outputs above, and I can't figure out how to extract the slopes and intercepts themselves from the lmerMod object. I expected these predictions to be the same as the `lm` models and don't understand why they're different.

```r
lme_rand_slope_mod <-lme4::lmer(y~x+(1+x|grp), data=dat, REML = FALSE)
```

```
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev. Corr
 grp      (Intercept) 3.6281       
          x           0.2571   0.77
 Residual             0.4778       
Number of obs: 30, groups:  grp, 3
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)            x  
     1.1102       0.8192
```

Comparison of the three slope/intercept values (boxes = fixed slope, circles = random). Note that while the circles appear to fall right on the line of best fit, they're actually deviating systematically.

```
dat$y_lmpred <- predict(lm_model, newdata=dat[,c("x", "grp")])
dat$y_lme_fixedpred <- predict(lme_fixed_slope_mod, newdata=dat[,c("x", "grp")])
dat$y_lme_randpred <- predict(lme_rand_slope_mod, newdata=dat[,c("x", "grp")])

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(color=grp), method="lm") +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y_lme_fixedpred, fill=grp), shape=22) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y_lme_randpred, fill=grp), shape=21)
```

[image: lmer model fits with both random slopes and random intercepts]

Which of these four methods is most apt for my data and will help me answer 1) whether x is a good predictor of y and 2) whether the slopes are indistinguishable for the subgroups in my real data set? What values should I report to show this?

Comment: I agree with CaroZ , I would not use random effects for a clustering variable that only has 3 levels. Single-level regression with group * x interaction would seem to work well. You can test the significance of x's slopes for each subgroup for instance via emmeans emtrends.

Answer (score 1):

The significant interaction between x and the subpopulation and is what tells you that the relationship between x and y differs according to the subpopulation, i.e. whether the slopes are different or not between subgroups.
I would first report the stat of the interaction. If this interaction is significant, i.e. if indeed the relationship between x and y differs according to the subgroup, it might mean that in some groups x is a good predictor of y but not in others.
To answer this I would produce an effect plot with the 'effects' package, look at the confidence intervals in each subgroup. If in some I could be fitting a flat line within the 95CIs, I would say x does not predict y in the given subgroup.
If not, x predicts y in the given subgroup.

I do not see the point of the random slopes and intercepts, but it might just be my opinion.

Comment: I agree in this situation, with only 3 groups, that the best approach would be to use a fixed slopes approach. But what if you had 300 groups? Would you still advocate for a regression with 299 fixed intercepts and another 299 interaction effects? The random approach reduces this to 5 parameters - 1) fixed slope mean, 2) fixed interaction, 3) random intercept variance, 4) random slope variance, 4) random slope-random intercept covariance.